# c programming print ascii value of char*

Tags: c, pointers, char, compiler-warnings, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to print the ascii value (ascii int numbers) of a `char*` for example `A` as 65  as on the [ascii table](http://www.ascii-code.com/).

Here is the code I have.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = 0;

    printf(" Hello World \n");
    printf("argv[0] is %s! \n",argv[0]);
    printf("argv[1] is %s! \n",argv[1]);
    printf("argv[2] is %s! \n",argv[2]);
    printf("argv[3] is %s! \n",argv[3]);

    if( argc == 4 )
    {
        printf("The first argument supplied is %s\n", argv[1]);
        printf("The second argument supplied is %s\n", argv[2]);
        printf("The third argument supplied is %s\n", argv[3]);
    }
    else if( argc > 4 )
    {
        printf("Too many arguments supplied.\n");
        exit( 1 );
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Not enough arguments supplied. \n");
        exit( 1 );
    }

    for(i = 1; i < 100; i++)
    {
        printf("i is %d argv[i] %d\n", i, argv[i]);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

I want these values to be entered from the command so this is what I put in.

```
./a.out A B C
```

When I compile it I get this warning.

> warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘char *’

If I cast the `argv[i]` to `(int)` I get this message.

> warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size

If I cast the `argv[i]` to `(int *)` I get this message.

> warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘int *’

Comment: Provided `argv[i]` is valid, `(int) *argv[i]` should work just fine (`argv` is an array of `char *`, so `*argv[i]` dereferences the pointer at `argv[i]`, effectively casting the first char to an int (which is legal in C). a `char` is always smaller than an int, so it can be promoted to `int`

Answer (score 2):

```
    printf("i is %d argv[i] %d\n", i, argv[i]);
```

is the problem causing line. Using incorrect format specifier is [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in C.

`argv` is of type `char**` but `%d` format specifier expects an `int`. So to print the ascii values of arguments, you'll need a nested loop over `argv`.

```
    for(j=1;j<argc; j++) {
       for(i=0;argv[j][i];i++) {
          printf("i is %d argv[i] %d\n", j, argv[j][i]);
       }
    }
```

Note that your loop condition is not correct. You only have `strlen(argv[j])` characters for each argument. So you can't arbitrarily print for `100` chars.

Move these printf statements

```
printf("argv[0] is %s! \n",argv[0]);
printf("argv[1] is %s! \n",argv[1]);
printf("argv[2] is %s! \n",argv[2]);
printf("argv[3] is %s! \n",argv[3]);
```

below the arguments checking so that you would only print them *after* arguments checking. Otherwise, you might end up accessing arguments that are not there if fewer arguments are passed.

Answer (score 0):

- **Point 1:** Don't use `argv[n]` directly until you have checked for `argc > n`. This also includes unchecked loops like

  ```
  for(i = 1; i < 100; i++)
  ```

  you'll end up accessing invalid memory after `i` gets equal to `argc`.
- **Point 2:** `argv[n]` is a null-terminated array or *string* (for valid cases), by default. You need `%s` format specifier to print that.

  That is, a command line `A` as the first argument to `a.out` is represented as `"A"` as `argv[1]` inside the program. It is not a `char` anymore, it is a *string*.